# Align page elements based on device orientation bootstrap

Tags: html, css, alignment, orientation

I designed a page with the help of bootstrap, with 2 image icons is it.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="text-center vcenter"><label  class="Title">Page title</label></div>
    <div class="span7 center" style="height:100%; padding-top:5%">
        <div style="float:left; text-align:center;"><img src="images/image1.png" class="img-responsive"></img><label class="iconText">Icon Text1</label> </div>
        <div style="float:right; text-align:center;"><img src="images/image2.png" class="img-responsive"></img><label class="iconText">Icon Text2</label> </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: url('images/3D/landing.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

I need to align these two images one below another on vertical orientation of mobile device and on the same line on horizontal orientation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstraps grid system to do the hard-work for you. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Adding col-md-6 to your div class means that your divs will start stacked on top of each other on mobile and tablet devices, then becomes horizontal on desktop. Read up on the grid-system in bootstrap.

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="float:left; text-align:center;"><img src="images/image1.png" class="img-responsive"></img><label class="iconText">Icon Text1</label></div>
<div class="col-md-6" style="float:right; text-align:center;"><img src="images/image2.png" class="img-responsive"></img><label class="iconText">Icon Text2</label> </div>
```

Let me know if you need any more help.

p.s. I kept your inline-styling but try using external stylesheets so that your html doesn't get so messy

Comment: Thanks...What I exactly need is, on horizontal orientation of device the two icons should be aligned horizontally. And on vertical orientation, it should be stacked on top of each other. On desktop, horizontal alignment is enough.